# Type Error: 'generator' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python

```
def activity_select(i):
    list(i)
    i.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
    n = len(i)                        # set n to length of i 
    solution = []
    print("Following activities are selected ")
    j = 0                             # first activity always selected
    solution.append(i[j][0])
    for k in range(n):                # loop through remainder of activities
        if i[k][1] >= i[k][2]:        # if activity has greater start time
            solution.append(i[k][0]) #
            j = k
            return solution

file = open('act.txt')
st = []
sn = 1
for line in file:
    l = line.rstrip()
    if '' not in l and len(st) > 0:
        print("Set", sn)
        solution = activity_select(st)
        print("Number of activities selected = ", len(solution))
        print("Activities: ", *solution)
        sn += 1
        st = []
else:
            st.append((int(i) for i in l.split()))
if len(st) > 0:
    print("Set ", sn)
    sol = activity_select(st)
    print("Number of activities selected = ", len(sol))
    print("Activities: ", *solution)
```

However I am getting the following errors

```
line 27, in <module>
    sol = activity_select(st)
line 9, in activity_select
    sol.append(v[i][0])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Is this related to the `st` variable? Or is it something else?

Comment: there's something missing, the exception clearly states that you want to use slice notations in a generator(`generator[1]`) which is not suported, but i dont see any generators in your code. The reason is because as its name implies generators do not have store the data, they are kind of 'ethereal' as in it generates the data on the fly, theres no data ahead nor behind

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple obvious errors here:

1. You converted your `i` argument to a `list` and didn't assign it back to `i`, so if it's *not* a `list`, the function is broken from the start. Use `i = list(i)` to replace `i` with the result of listifying
2. You call `st.append((int(i) for i in l.split()))` which is calling `append` with a generator (created via a generator expression). If it's supposed to be a `list`, use brackets, not parens: `st.append([int(i) for i in l.split()])`. If each result should be added separately, use `extend` instead: `st.extend(int(i) for i in l.split())`

Problem #2 is almost certainly the source of your current error, but fixing #1 is important for making your code usable with non-lists (and to avoid having it mutate the caller's copy of the `list` even when it works).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug your code seeing that you are reading of a file we do not have. My guess would be you are trying slice a generator, a quick glance shows that you have a generator expression here:

```
st.append((int(i) for i in l.split()))
```

Try changing it to `st.append([int(i) for i in l.split()])` to get a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem with your code is:

```
st.append((int(i) for i in l.split()))
```

because you're appending a generator with is un-indexable, un-sliceable , un-subscriptable , so use a list comprehension which is indexable, sliceable, subscriptable.

So instead of:

```
st.append((int(i) for i in l.split()))
```

Do:

```
st.append([int(i) for i in l.split()])
```